# How to maintain MongoClient connection as a 'singleton' for a TestSuite in groovy/ Soap UI

Tags: groovy, singleton, soapui, ready-api

I have tried as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993841/create-a-mongo-connection-and-make-it-alive-for-execution-of-an-entire-test-suit).

I am able to access the connection object, but it says

> IllegalStateException - state should be: open

Below is the snippet which I have tried.

```
//set connection
testSuite.metaClass.db = db 

//get connection (i am trying to access it from the same testSuite for testing purpose)
def connection = testSuite.db.getConnection()
for(def userObj :connection.User.find()){
 log.info userObj
}
```

Comment: Please state your question

Comment: Is your database running? Have you followed exactly as mentioned in the linked answer? Because that for that user.